# Gulp error on node_module that has scss

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gulp, gulp-sass

I recently npm installed the node module [react-calendar-timeline](https://github.com/namespace-ee/react-calendar-timeline) .

After implementing it one of my components, I ran gulp to build.

gulp threw an error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
    SyntaxError:
    /var/www/monitor/node_modules/react-calendar-timeline/modules/lib/Timeline.scss:1
    $item-color: white;
               ^
    ParseError: Unexpected token
```

My gulpfile file for this component looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    gulp.src('js/ScheduleMain.js')
      .pipe(browserify({transform:'babelify'}))
      .pipe(concat('ScheduleMain.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('static/dist/js'));
```

It seems as though I am not able to handle the .scss file of the module I have installed. What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an issue related more to `gulp-browserify` than your build script.

Keep in mind that **gulp-browserify is long dead**, in fact it's been more than an year since the last update; this is from it's [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify):

> NOTE: THIS PLUGIN IS NO LONGER MAINTAINED , checkout the recipes by gulp team for reference on using browserify with gulp.

Browserify natively supports streming and with just a pair of plugins you can trasform that stream to be gulp compatible, I suggest you to take a look at gulp's examples folder, more specifically to this [example using browserify](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-uglify-sourcemap.md).

By the way, what's the point in running `gulp-concat` when in your stream theres only one file?

Comment: @AssasinsMod Thanks for the reply. I use gulp-browserify just fine for building my other files, but why does it break when using a module that uses scss? I took a peak in this file and it looks like its webpack based. I would prefer to not switch everything in my gulp build script to using browserify over gulp-browserify if I didn't have to. Also, I appreciate the example link, but how would this solve my problem of SCSS?

Comment: @ApathyBear sorry for the late response. I browsed that project's source and noticed that the distribution build too has a `require('Timeline.scss')`.
Sadly this means that you must either use webpack for building or modify the Timeline's project source.

Comment: Hey @AssassinsMod, thanks. Why is building with webpack the only way to handle scss currently? I have altered the source code directly to not include Timeline.scss and that works fine.

Comment: Browserify's require ~= node's requires which is basically importing a module into the current stript. Webpack on the other hand overloads the require statement in a way that, with the appropriate loader, it transforms any kind of resource into javascript.

Webpack's motto is: "Everything is representable as javascript". This comes handy for certain use cases (see [hot module replacement](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html)) but also causes some headaches.

Comment: @ApathyBear the one at fault in this case is Timeline's developer, assuming that everybody uses webpack and not providing alternatives for who doesn't.